# Running adb shell programmatically leads to Cannot run program "adb": error=13, Permission denied

Tags: android

I'm trying to add some code to help debugging an issue I've got with alarm/job scheduling on a user device, so that I can dump the current state of the alarms/jobs to a file for sending to me.  I#m trying:

```
File outputFile;
String cmd;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    outputFile = new File(logDirectory, "jobs.txt");
    cmd = "adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler > " + outputFile;
} else {
    outputFile = new File(logDirectory, "alarms.txt");
    cmd = "adb shell dumpsys alarm > " + outputFile;
}
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

But I'm getting:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb": error=13, Permission denied
```

Thing is, running the following command in the same place in the code is fine... outputs the log to a file, so clearly file writing permissions are granted:

```
File logFile = new File(logDirectory, "logs.txt");
cmd = "logcat -v time -f " + logFile + " *:V";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run adb on the device itself, i.e. as if it were the PC issuing the commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871391/run-adb-on-the-device-itself-i-e-as-if-it-were-the-pc-issuing-the-commands)

Comment: @kandroidj why does the error say "permission denied" when running "adb" rather than command not found or something?  Is there any way of querying the information that I need, i.e. alarms or jobs?  I thought maybe the issue is that using the command I'm using also gets info for other apps, and hence the permission problem, but all I want is info for my own application anyway.