# One Android device run adb logcat against another

Tags: adb, logcat

I had always wondered if it was possible to have on android device collect logcat from another. Consider the following image I have attached. The goal would be to create an application that could find and attach adb to another device.

This would eliminate the need to carry a laptop or PC to collect information for a device. Any help with this would be amazing.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871391/run-adb-on-the-device-itself-i-e-as-if-it-were-the-pc-issuing-the-commands