# Can we execute adb shell programtically in android?

Tags: android

I need to know, can we execute adb shell script programtically in android, because i need that script running when application start for be as a device owner in kiosk mode feature like this below :

`adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.test/.AdminReceiver`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your best choice would be Runtime class, it can be used like:

```
String yourCommand = "adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.test/.AdminReceiver";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(yourCommand);
```

Comment: You should fix your variable names to be consistent.

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: i got this error sir ..

Cannot run program "adb": error=13, Permission denied

Comment: Actually it looks like as long as the approach mentioned above will work for executing shell commands in general it is not that simple when it comes to `adb` commands specifically. For more detailed explanation it was already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682468/4153947
and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871391/run-adb-on-the-device-itself-i-e-as-if-it-were-the-pc-issuing-the-commands 
Thus I would propose that you can mark your question as duplicate and read the above threads.

Comment: @JhonDoe I think you will need to root your phone in order to execute `adb` from an app.