# Run adb shell command programmatically

Tags: java, android, command-line, permissions, adb

I'm trying to build a simple support app to execute some of adb shell commands like "adb shell wm overscan -35,0,-55,0" to hide Black Bottom Bar. I will run this app as system on rooted device.

The problem is that I couldn't find any working solution in the internet. I already tried next solutions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74190894/22536158

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381888/22536158

These do nothing if i write command without adb shell like: "wm overscan -35,0,-55,0" and if I add adb shell then it throws:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb": error=13, Permission denied
```

Moreover, I've tried to use ProcessBuilder:

```
ProcessBuilder("wm overscan -35,0,-55,0").start()
```

and it throws

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "wm overscan -35,0,-55,0": error=13, Permission denied
```

Can someone please explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you using Shizuku API which enable "adb" command for other android apps.